# How does getcount() in array adapter return values without returing array size explicitly?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

This question may sound stupid but I cannot help myself but ask here.

I know in  Array adapter, `getcount()` method is used to return the number of elements to display in the list. I also know that we need to override it and return the size of the array or number of lists to display in the layout.

In many online blogs, I saw that the `getcount()` method is not overridden but still, the list is displayed and when I try to do it the same way, I do not get any lists displayed unless I override getcount() .

So my question is

1) Is it really necessary to override method to display lists? How does `getcount` method know how many lists to display without overriding it as it is done in many online blogs.

2) when it is not necessary to override `getcount()` and still get the views as intended.

I am just learning and hope you to understand. Thank you

Comment: Thank you , But is it possible to get views without overriding getcount() .Because in some online blogs they did not override and still they got the list data.

Comment: Don't confuse ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, ListAdapter. In ListAdapter you have to do everything yourself. ArrayAdapter takes an array and does everything it can for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. inside adapter (not list itself) - yes, you have to override this method and return number of items (e.g. straight from list.size())
2. show these "many online blogs links", will verify. some adapters (like base [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)) may have automated counting items, especially when they are passed in constructor in `List` - this class is well-known collection, so there is prepared adapter for this common usage, but if you have `YourOwnClass` populated by own resolution, then you have to extend adapter and handle counting by self
3. show some code... always

Comment: As you asked ,link to one such blog is given below when the getcount() is not overridden [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd)

Comment: adapter under link is `ArrayAdapter` which takes `List` as parameter and have "automated" bypassing `getCount()` to `list.size()`